# How can I get dynamic content from a http web request through java

Tags: java, javascript, http, dynamic

The output HTML code is not complete, because the javascript in it is not executed.

Do I need to run the javascript somehow?

I want to get the content of a live-bidding website through java.

Comment: post some code, add more info, anything..... we cannot help you like this!

Answer (score 0):

Rather than scraping the dynamic content, it would probably be more practical to figure out what the javascript is doing (e.g. what AJAX calls it is making) and code your application do the same thing.

---

You haven't mentioned which website you are talking about, but if they want you to do this kind of thing, it is likely that they will have developed a "web API" for people like you to use.  And the flip-side is that they may not want people gaining an unfair advantage over other users by doing this kind of thing.

Either way, check the site's Terms of Service, etcetera ... or you might find yourself in legal trouble.

Comment: I tried to figure out what the javascript do, but it's simply too much code.

https://www.interwetten.com/en/sportsbook/live

Checked the terms & conditions, also I don't get an unfair advantage, because I just want to place bids on a calculated pattern while not sitting and waiting in front of my pc

Comment: Sounds like you didn't try hard enough :-)

Comment: Alternatively, read http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/easy-web-scraping-with-nodejs or one of the other easily Googleable resources on "web scraping javascript"